# How to make this query aggregate the time-grouping correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I try to perform a grouping based on rows based on a string and a eventtime. The identical strings must be grouped with eventtime occurrances within period of 30 minutes. If there are more then 30 minutes between eventtimes, there is a new groupset.

So far I found the following attempt (by many similiar, but this is simpliest). With the comments below, i also note that i missunderstood what it does. It does a 30 minutes rounding, which won't fill my need. Perhaps "grouping based on 'within daterange'" is more accurace?.

```
SELECT  min(eventtime) as mintime, 
        max(eventtime) as maxtime, 
        [stringfield],
        count([stringfield]) as qty
FROM Searches
GROUP BY datediff(mi, '19900101', eventtime) / 30, 
         [stringfield]
ORDER BY min(eventtime)
```

Resulting in this table
[image]

See the red and blue arrows. Those two lines should be aggregated. Red arrows says 'identical strings'. The blue arrow says that 'the maxtime are within 30 min range'.

I have also tried 31 minutes without success, in case of >= issue. Can someone see by this T-SQL why it go wrong? And how I can fix it?

[Edit]
The expected output is the two rows with arrows grouped. Which means i expect five rows in the output. The 5th row should not exist (aggregated into first). Which results in Qty 3 in the first row, the maxtime will be '2013-06-01 08:55'.

```
2013-06-01 08:00 | 2013-06-01 08:55 | 0x2BBF4........26BD38 | 3
```

Comment: Could you provide the output you need for the data you have shown?

Comment: What is wrong with your result? Row 1 is in the group from 8:00:00 to 8:29:59, and row 5 in the group from 8:30:00 to 8:59:59. These are distinct groups.

Comment: That group by is screwy...are you in MySQL by any chance? Row one is an aggregate of atleast two values (min and max being different gives it away)...how does your group by understand which of the rows in the aggregate to group by?

Comment: Put the group by clause `datediff(mi, '19900101', eventtime) / 30` in the select clause to see what is going on and why these are not grouped together.

Comment: @FrankPI Yes. The first row end in 08:25:00, from 08:25:00 there are 30 minutes to 08:55:00. That row fits into 30 minutes treshold.

Comment: @Independent no it doesn't because the first row starts at 08:00:00. So it has already grouped two values (*hence the `qty` of 2 at the last column*), one at 8:00 and one at 8:25 and that is its group. if it expands to fit the 8:55 it means that the group will be from 8:00 to 8:55 (*55 minutes which sounds wrong by your requirements*)

Comment: @Gaby Thank's for clarify. In fact it's a treshold by 30 minutes from max date in group, not a 30 min rounding, so i adjust my description.

Comment: Added the sql-server tag because the syntax looks a lot like SQL Server.

Comment: So @Independent it should group all 3 values even if first is 55 minutes from third, because there is one in the middle with distance less than 30 from each ?

Comment: Gaby, yes. And that can continue for a lifetime, so long there exist identical strings within 30 minutes (which won't be, but to clarify the requirement).

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server are you using? What you describe can be done more easily in 2012 version, with the newly added analytic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2012 version of SQL-Server, you can use the analytic `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions for this:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT
        stringfield
      , eventtime
      , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY stringfield
                                 ORDER BY eventtime )
      , leadtime = LEAD(eventtime) OVER ( PARTITION BY stringfield
                                          ORDER BY eventtime )
      , firsttime= MIN(eventtime) OVER ( PARTITION BY stringfield )
      , diff = CASE WHEN DATEADD(minute, 30, eventtime)
                         >= LEAD(eventtime) 
                            OVER ( PARTITION BY stringfield
                                   ORDER BY eventtime )
                    THEN 0 ELSE 1
               END 
    FROM 
        Searches
  ) 
SELECT 
    stringfield
  , mintime = COALESCE(LAG(leadtime) OVER ( PARTITION BY stringfield
                                            ORDER BY eventtime )
               ,firsttime) 
  , maxtime = eventtime 
  , qty = rn - COALESCE(LAG(rn) OVER ( PARTITION BY stringfield
                                       ORDER BY eventtime ) 
                       ,0)
FROM 
    cte 
WHERE 
    diff = 1
ORDER BY 
    stringfield,
    maxtime ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8b15/25)**.

Comment: Yes! Of course! LAG and LEAD with PARTITION, there you nailed it. I have the environment available first at tomorrow for performance-test and make reflections over the T-SQL. Thank's so far.